# ZFS adding new device to RAIDZ

Tags: zfs

I wondering about problem with adding new device to ZFS RAIDZ.

I'm thinking about it only theoretically:
After destroying ZFS pool with only RAIDZ in it. The data should be still there on the disks.

Is there a way to create new RAIDZ with old disks? If so, it should be almost the same way to add a new extra hard drive (or more) to the new RAIDZ. Only extra thing in this case is recalculate all parity.
Am I wrong?

So for now the ***main*** question is:

**Is there some way to create new RAIDZ with old disks (from old RAIDZ) without adding new extra disk?**

Comment: See [this question](http://serverfault.com/questions/190207/how-can-i-add-one-disk-to-an-existing-raidz-zpool).

Comment: This question about adding new HDD to raidz, it is not my main question.

Comment: Are you saying you want to re-create a RAIDZ that has been destroyed _and_ recover its data? This isn't possible and is what backups are for.

Comment: The main idea not about recovering the data as you can read above. But yes it is almoust the same question: Is it possible to re-create a RAIDZ that has been destroyed?

Comment: No,  it's not possible.

Comment: Seems like more of a generic unix question.  Maybe it belongs on unix.se?

Comment: The answer is pretty straightforward.  It's "no" in the context of the OP's question.

Answer (score 2):

This is not posible. You cannot expand an existing RAIDZ pool by adding disks.

Comment: You answered to the second question but not to the main one.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. In any case, you can't modify any RAIDZ setup. I'm not sure what you mean by "extra disk".

Comment: "extra disk" is a new one, for example never used before.

Answer (score 0):

You can re-create the raidz again using the same disks, but the data previously on those disks would be lost.

For example, if you had a raidz with 5 drives in it... ie. sd1 sd2 sd3 sd4 sd5... you would simply run "zpool create foo raidz sd1 sd2 sd3 sd4 sd5"

If you wanted to re-create the same pool, using the same old disks, AND add in a new disk (ie. sd6), you would use the command "zpool create foo raidz sd1 sd2 sd3 sd4 sd5 sd6"

Again, you cannot preserve/restore the data from the old pool you deleted, but you can re-use the same old disks to create a new pool with the same name as the old pool... and add a new drive to it if you wanted to.